# Is it possible to trigger build of some specific revision remotely?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

Is it possible to trigger build of some specific revision remotely?
As I can see it is possible to configure authentication token only.
But not revision.
Now I use following URL in SVN post-commit script to call build remotely after commit:
http://tsthost/hudson/view/ci/job/tst_trunk/build?token=CHECK_TST_TRUNK

But I would like to use something like next URL to build specific revision:
http://tsthost/hudson/view/ci/job/tst_trunk/build?token=CHECK_TST_TRUNK&revision=123

Is there a plugin for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You can use next approach:

1. Make your build parameterized.
2. Add parameter `revision` (with default value `HEAD` to support regular runs)
3. In build script add line `svn update -r $revision`.

Comment: It will not help. There could be several commits before HUDSON starts to update working copy.

Comment: I meant to run update in your hudson job. Right before the actions you want to do to this specific revision are going to be performed.

Comment: What exactly revision should I use in update? I need automated builds. Who will set this revision?

Comment: In your question you said `But I would like to use something like next URL to build specific revision: http://tsthost/hudson/view/ci/job/tst_trunk/build?token=CHECK_TST_TRUNK&revision=123` -- so the caller of the build should know the revision.